# помогите с ноутбуком

Tags: разработка-игр, ноутбук

MSI Crosshair 15 (i7-12700H/RTX3070Ti)
MSI
Экран: 15.6'' FullHD IPS 144Hz
Процессор: Intel® Core™ i7-12700H (3.5 GHz – 4.7 GHz ) (14-Ядра; #производительных ядер 6, #эффективных ядер 8; 20-Потоков)
Видеокарта: GeForce RTX3070Ti NVIDIA 8GB/256Bit/GDDR6
ОЗУ: 16GB DDR4 (32GB=+65 у.е)
Накопитель: 1TB PCIe® NVMe™ M.2 SSD

какие игры потянет, и на какой графике? к примеру киберпанк, детройт, колда, ведьмак и т.д. Хороший ли ноутбук?